# How to expand a variable containing another variable in a Windows Command Prompt window?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, environment-variables

I have a variable `x` with the value `"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"`. In other words, the command `set x` produces the output shown below.

```
x="%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
```

I then entered the command below in a hope of replacing `%USERPROFILE%` with
its assigned value of `C:\Users\Fred Flintstone`.

```
set x=%x%
```

I then tested by entering the command `set x`. I expected the output to be the following.

```
x="C:\Users\Fred Flintstone\Downloads"
```

But, instead the result was unchanged, as shown below.

```
x="%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"
```

What Windows command would I use to change the assigned value of the variable `x` from the string `"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads"` to
`"C:\Users\Fred Flintstone\Downloads"` by replacing `%USERPROFILE%` with its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in command prompt:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('echo %x%') do @set x=%a
```

Or this in a batch script:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo %x%') do @set x=%%a
```